# Hide Core Data advanced settings warning

Tags: cocoa, core-data

In a project using Core Data I've set the "No Action"-rule to some models. This generates the following warning:

"Setting the No Action Delete Rule on  is an advanced setting"

Now I know this is an advanced setting and I should keep track of what we're doing with the relationships, but that's exactly what I'm doing.

(To be more precise, if I stop Core Data from doing anything on delete I get a pretty big boost when deleting things manually).

So how do I disable the warning?

All I could find on the intertubes was this:

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/173698-core-data-compiler-warning.html

And I agree with the poster that it's not the cleanest way to solve a compiler warning.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Ran into [How to disable no inverse relationship warning for CoreData in Xcode 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221813/how-to-disable-no-inverse-relationship-warning-for-coredata-in-xcode-4-2) and found the MOMC_ warnings. Even after enabling all of them, still getting the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this particular warning via the method you've mentioned in your question.

You may still be seeing the warning in the errors navigator if you are showing all issues instead of just issues from the latest build. (The filter icons are in the bottom bar at the bottom of the navigator.)