# CoreData dilemma: entity without inverse relationship

Tags: ios, database, core-data

I have entities `Image` and `Post`. Post has a uni-directional Nullify relationship to Image. It's a relationship and not an attribute because I want to benefit from lazy loading of relationships, making initial fetches of Post entities very fast. As you can guess, `Image` contains image data.

Apple generally discourages uni-directional relationships ([Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html)) unless there a good reason not to have an inverse relationship.

My reason for not having it is `Image` is a generic entity, so having inverse relationships to all entities that use it seemed like overkill. However, I wonder if there is a better way to go about this without violating Apple's recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parent entities.

[image]

`Comment`, `BlogPost` and `Tweet` all inherit the `images` relationship. And the inverse relationship points to a TextContent object, which can be a Comment, BlogPost, Tweet or TextContent itself.

Comment: Good, clean approach where I can maintain inverse relationships.

Comment: It's a nice and clean solution that I have been considering introducing as well, but I keep hearing that inheritance in Core Data is inefficient as it will inflate the underlying database because all attributes (of parents+children) will end up in the same table and cost a lot of space?

Answer (score 0):

As Apple says... [Unidirections Relationships](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW6)

> It is not strictly necessary to model a relationship in both
>   directions

BTW I think attributes also could be loaded lazily (by system) if CoreData detects that is better to do this...

You can be interested in this then to
[avoid warnings in your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642392/how-to-avoid-core-data-warning-entity-should-have-an-inverse-relationship)