# remove Core Data Warnings for older models

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, xcode5, warnings

I am fixing a core data model.
I create a new model version, and fix all the conditions that are causing warnings.
I am still getting warnings for the older model versions though.

I am looking for the best way of getting rid of/hiding those warnings, without impacting the display of warnings project-wide

Comment: can you elaborate and show the warnings?

Comment: The warning is the "Setting the No action delete rule is an advanced setting".

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221813/how-to-disable-no-inverse-relationship-warning-for-coredata-in-xcode-4-2

Comment: this doesn't answer my question. I know how to fix the warning or hide the warning project wide, the question is about hiding them for previous model versions.

Comment: I am facing the same above said issue.. I have cleared my coredata warnings (MOMC_NO_INVERSE_RELATIONSHIP_WARNINGS) in my latest migrated version. But the warnings are still shown for the previous momd versions.. Is there any way to get rid of them yet ?
We can set a flag for it in build setting but just to suppress the warning which will not be of help as that is going to hide any future momd  warning..