# How to fix Core-Data old version(xcdatamodel)'s warning?

Tags: xcode, core-data, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I knew that modifying core-data previous version breaks the light-weight migration. 
But I have inverse relationship warnings on old versions of data model.

1. I tried removing old versions that are used before launching first version of our app. I followed this [SO question, "How to delete an old/unused Data Model Version in xCode 4"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708392/how-to-delete-an-old-unused-data-model-version-in-xcode-4)

   - It removes warning(Of course it should)
   - But I cannot run our app anymore

   **I think I should keep every versions even though it is not related to light-weight migration**
2. I saw this [SO question, "How to disable no inverse relationship warning for CoreData in Xcode 4.2?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221813/how-to-disable-no-inverse-relationship-warning-for-coredata-in-xcode-4-2). And I tried setting the MOMC_NO_INVERSE_RELATIONSHIP_WARNINGS to YES.

   - It doesn't removes warning
   - And I don't want my future mistake, missing inverse setting, also be ignored.

   **I think this option is not for my case**

I don't want to see compiler warning for old version of data model(.xcdatamodel).
Because these models are not used so that warnings are not significant.

But I want to see future inverse relationship warning on newer version of data model.

What option can I take?

Comment: This is still an issue...