# Can I suppress the "...has more than 100 properties" CoreData warning?

Tags: xcode, core-data, clang

I have found many questions on SO regarding ignoring (or fixing) the CoreData warning about an object having more than 100 properties, but I would like to completely **suppress** the warning from our build. Is this possible? We are using XCode 7.1 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Isn’t your model wrongly modelled? You should split it to smaller parts and relations.

Comment: That sounds like a terrifying data model.

Comment: We're working on fixing it; we know it's a problem :) I would just like to get the build to have 0 warnings.

Comment: Keep the warnings to remind you to fix the data model!

Comment: You *could* represent your model in code, or JSON, or even CSV so it doesn't go through the model compiler.  Now, I wouldn't recommend it for that reason, but I have grown quite fond of code-based models.  They are, to me, much easier to edit and test.  I miss the GUI picture for relationships, but I've gotten quite used to it (and I have a number of helper methods and import/export formats by now).  This is especially useful for serving model schemas over RESTful services.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way!! Although now that I've come back I see [@Willeke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244136/willeke) posted the basic answer two days ago.

Apparently this has been available for [a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221813/how-to-disable-no-inverse-relationship-warning-for-coredata-in-xcode-4-2) (since 4.2).

- `Project > Build Settings`
- Search for `MOMC`
- Change "Suppress momc warnings for entities with more than 100 properties" to `YES`.

[image]